# multimap less_equal leading to wrong find() results

Tags: c++

So, instead of an array I decided to use a multimap, so that I could store the repeating values along with some other value(which acts as a pair).
So, when I declared a multi-map like

```
multimap<int,int,less_equal<int> > M;
multimap<int,int,less_equal<int> >::iterator it,it2;
```

And then inserted all the elements into it, say

```
(10,1), (2,2), (8,3), (2,2), (8,1)
```

and then iterated through it, I got what I desired:

```
2 2 
2 2
8 1 
8 3 
10 1
```

But now, the find function just doesn't work
Like, if I want to find a number, say

```
it2=M.find(temp);
```

where temp is some value that exists in the multimap, say 8, it just ignores it and doesn't find it! The find function was working when I didn't include the less_equal, but since that is what I want in my program, now I am struggling with my code. Could anyone suggest a remedy to it? As well as the reason why find fails to work correctly?

Comment: Think of it this way: multimap's ONLY valid way to compare keys is to use the operator you pass in. Thus, a key is equal iff  (!(compare(a,b)||compare(b,a)). Normally, the comparitor you pass in is less, so you get (!((a<b)||(b<a)). BUT in the case of less than or equal, you need (!((a<=b)||(b<=a)) which is an overlapping comparison, so no keys will ever return true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparator must define a *strict* ordering; that is, it must return `false` when comparing two equivalent values. Otherwise, logic that depends on this will fail. In particular, `find(temp)` looks for a key equivalent to `temp`, that satisfies

```
!compare(key,temp) && !compare(temp,key)
```

which will not happen unless the ordering is strict.

`less` (the default comparator) is strict; `less_equal` is not, so can't be used.

Comment: True that. But when I use less, it gives output on iteration like, (2,3), (2,2), (8,2), (8,1), (10,1). The keys do not get sorted in the order I require them to be in this case :/

Comment: @AbbaShareen It seems your desired ordering depends on the value as well, not only on the key. Which means that canceptually, you don't really have a map from `int` to `int`, you have a set of int pairs with a defined ordering. So represent it as such.

Comment: Yup. Even now I feel multimap is of no use here. I guess multiset should be a better bet here. But then, how should I proceed with multiset for the same case? Do I need to have an explicit sorting function for that?

Comment: @AbbaShareen: `multimap` only sorts by key (the first element of the pair), not by value (the second element). If you want to sort by both, use `set<pair<int,int>>` (or `multiset`, if you want duplicates) instead.

Comment: @AbbaShareen `std::less<std::pair<int, int>>` will do lexicographical comparison on the pairs - `(1, 2)` will come before `(1, 3)`, but after `(0, 5)`. If that's what you want, use it. If you want something else, you'll have to write your own comparator.

Comment: Now that I am using a multiset, the sorting is indeed occurring in the desired manner. But, the find function doesn't seem to work. Every time I use something like `it2=M.find(temp);` it gives an error as error: `no matching function for call to 'std::multiset<std::pair<int, int> >::find(int&)`

Answer (score 1):

The comparator for an associative container must induce a strict weak ordering on the key type. `std::less_equal` is not a strict weak ordering. In particular, it is not strict because  `x <= x` for some `x` (in fact, for all `x`). Instead, you should use `std::less`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a less (no less equal) comparer.

Two keys are equivalent if:

> That is, two keys k1 and k2 are considered to be equivalent if for the
>   comparison object comp, comp(k1, k2) == false && comp(k2, k1) ==
>   false.

(From 23.2.4 Associative containers)